# C# unit testing a class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm doing unit testing with a class library and I'm stuck on how to test the method. I need to test scenarios like check if a password with less than 8 characters cannot be accepted, check if a password with 8 or more characters can be accepted and check if a password with space in the front cannot be accepted.

The code below is from the class library.

```
public class PasswordChecker
{
    public bool CheckPassword(string pwd)
    {
        if (pwd.Length >= 8 && !pwd.StartsWith(""))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

The code below is from the testing project.

```
[TestClass]
public class PasswordCheckerTest

{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckPassword8CharsLong()
    {
        string validPassword = "12345678";
        string invalidPassword = "abc";

        PasswordChecker checker = new PasswordChecker();

        Assert.IsTrue(checker.CheckPassword(validPassword));
        Assert.IsFalse(checker.CheckPassword(invalidPassword));

    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem ? If you don't know how to get started, i suggest you check the relevant [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx).

Comment: !pwd.StartsWith("")   looks strange

Comment: state your problem. also seperate the assertions into different methods. and agreeing with @dlxeon, if you have a problem startswith("") is possibly the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the error is due to `pwd.StartsWith("")` statement, however looking at your test, there are too many tests in one test method, it should be split into 3 methods,

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenValidPassword_WhenCheckPassword_ThenReturnTrue(){
         var password= "12345678";

         var sut = new PasswordChecker();
         var result = sut.CheckPassword(password);

          Assert.IsTrue(result );   
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenPasswordLessThan8Characters_WhenCheckPassword_ThenReturnFalse(){
         var password= "1278";

         var sut = new PasswordChecker();
         var result = sut.CheckPassword(password);

          Assert.IsFalse(result );   
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenPasswordStartWithSpace_WhenCheckPassword_ThenReturnFalse(){
         var password= " 12345678";

         var sut = new PasswordChecker();
         var result = sut.CheckPassword(password);

          Assert.IsFalse(result );   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be testing those two conditions in one test. Also, you can make your CheckPassword method static as it should have no side effects.

```
[TestClass]
public class PasswordCheckerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckPassword_PasswordLessThanEightCharacters_ReturnsFalse()
    {
        string invalidPassword = "1234567";

        PasswordChecker checker = new PasswordChecker();

        Assert.IsFalse(checker.CheckPassword(invalidPassword));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckPassword_PasswordLongerThanSevenCharacters_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        string validPassword= "12345678";

        PasswordChecker checker = new PasswordChecker();

        Assert.IsTrue(checker.CheckPassword(validPassword));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pwd.Length < 8 || pwd.Contains(" ") == true ){ //VALID }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

I would write your code this way. If password is not null and not starts with space and 8 characters or more

```
public static bool CheckPassword(string pwd)
{
   return pwd != null && !pwd.StartsWith(" ") && pwd.Length >= 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use the AAA principle, that is:

A: arrange where you initialize what is needed to call the method to be tested.

A: act where you actually make the call.

A: assert where you make the assertion that you've got what you were expecting.